# Variable Expansion Adding Braces to Original String Value

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

NOTE: I missed a syntax issue in my script that was causing this.  I was passing ${bar} as {$bar}.  This can be removed or locked or whatever is done with these types of questions.

---

I'm trying to test a script I am writing.  To view the contents of a variable, I'm attempting to echo it from the function it is passed to.  When it does, the expanded variable has braces added around it.  Any idea why it's doing this and pointers on how I can prevent it?  I'm assuming that if I passed the variable to a command, it would include the braces which would likely cause an error.  Please correct me if I'm wrong in this assumption.  Code is something like this:

```
editncopy()
{
  for i in {1..5}; do echo ${!i}; done
}

s=myserver
adir=/another/dir/
foo=/some/path/to/file.sh
bar=username@${s}:${adir}

editncopy string1 string2 ${foo} ${bar} ${s}
```

Output is like this:

```
[me@home dir]$ ./myscript.sh
string1
string2
/some/path/to/file.sh
{username@server:/another/dir/}
myserver
[me@home dir]$
```

It's always the $4 variable in the function that adds braces ({username@server:/another/dir/} should be just username@server:/another/dir/).  I tried echoing it on its own (echo $4), but it didn't matter.

In a nutshell, the script is going to modify the contents of another script using sed, then copy it out to other servers using scp.

Comment: I do not get that result (and you shouldn't). What shell are you working with? Is that your actual code? It isn't the actual output of that code.

Comment: Extra braces around the parameter during the call to the function?

Comment: Why are you using `${!i}` in the function? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `${bar}` mistyped as `{$bar}` when you use the function? Because that would add the braces.

Comment: And yeah, using `${!i}` there seems a bit weird. Something like `for x in "$@" ; do echo "$x" ; done` would seem more usual. Or `"${@:1:5}"` to just pick the first five arguments.

Comment: Using /bin/bash.  michaelhome, this isn't the first time I've run across something odd that didn't work on my system, but worked fine when others tried it.  As far as the code goes, the names have been changed to protect the innocent, but yeah, that's pretty much it. JeffSchaller, I will try removing them and see if it helps.  Kusalananda, trying to save myself some typing. ${!i} expands out to $1 $2 $3 etc... with each loop.

Comment: Well, dumb mistake on my part.  Apparently my eyes were going buggy.  I had  editncopy string1 string2 ${foo} {$bar} ${s} as @ilkkachu suggested.

Comment: I guess this question doesn't add much value since it was a missed syntax error on my part.  Seems like a good candidate for deletion, or whatever is done with these kinds of questions.  Thanks, everyone for your time.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the arguments passed to a function (this also works for iterating over the arguments in scripts):

```
#!/bin/sh

foo () {
    for i in "$@"; do
        printf 'Argument is "%s"\n' "$i"
    done
}

foo a b "c d" e "f g h"
```

Output:

```
Argument is "a"
Argument is "b"
Argument is "c d"
Argument is "e"
Argument is "f g h"
```

Or, with your values:

```
s=myserver
adir=/another/dir/
foo=/some/path/to/file.sh
bar=username@${s}:${adir}
foo string1 string2 ${foo} ${bar} ${s}
```

which generates

```
Argument is "string1"
Argument is "string2"
Argument is "/some/path/to/file.sh"
Argument is "username@myserver:/another/dir/"
Argument is "myserver"
```

It is likely that you have a typo in your code that swaps the `$` and `{` in `${bar}`:

```
$ foo {$bar}
Argument is "{username@myserver:/another/dir/}"
```